# Download a file using vb.net or C#

Tags: vb.net, download

this code allow me to download a file from internet using vb.net :

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
   DownloadClient = New WebClient
   Dim Url As New Uri("http://www.domain.com/download")
   DownloadClient.DownloadFileAsync(Url,"C:\file.ext")
End If
```

but the problem that sometimes the link needs to redirect to the link that downloading the file, so is there a way to get the name of downloaded file to use it in place of file.ext! thanks :)